# How to display a specific value in an excel cell from another worksheet by association

Tags: excel, formula-editor

I'm not very good at expressing this, but I'll try.

I have two worksheets, one containing a number of calculations, the other is a summary sheet.

I want the summary sheet to display the calculation results in a column based on the type chosen on the summary sheet.

For example:

The calculation sheet contains a number of different window types and their related frame factors. The summary sheet contains all wall types and their related window types. I want to be able to type into the summary sheet what window type is used in that particular wall type and I then want the next column to display the relevant frame factor from the window type sheet.

I hope this makes sense.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Are the window types, frame factors in the calculation sheet, and the window types in the summary sheet arranged in a single column?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a `VLOOKUP`.

Assuming that the Window Types in the Summary Sheet is in column B, that the Window Types in the Calculations Sheet in column A, the Frame Factors in the Calculation sheet in column B, and lastly that the sheets contain column labels in the first row:

```
=VLOOKUP(B2, 'Calculations Sheet'!A:B, 2, 0)
```

It will use the value contained in B2 (Window type), look for it in the Calculations Sheet in column A, and return the exact corresponding value in the second column (column B).